# Symfony - Expected value of type '' got "string" instead

Tags: php, mysql, api, symfony, postman

I am trying to pass id from one country table to user table but I can't' pass this error..

> Expected value of type "ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\Country" for association field "ProjectBundle\Base\Entity\User#$country", got "string" instead.

My User entity class

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"user_data"})
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
 * @JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $country;


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $country
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
}
```

My User service

```
 public function registerUser($country)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setCountry($country);

    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();


    return $user;
}
```

My User controller

```
 public function registerUserAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams(['country_id']);

    $country = $this->data['country_id'];

    $user =  $this->get('member')->registerUser($country);

    return $this->success($user);
}
```

So I am passing country_id value via postman and I get this error.

Comment: show us the user entity.

Comment: I post it first above.

Comment: can you post full info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that

```
$user->setCountry()
```

expects an instance of your Country Entity. But you try to call it with the ID of an country. Doctrine does not fetch the Entity from the given ID.

To fix this you have two options:

1. fetch the country with the ID

   in your user Service:

   ```
   public function registerUser($countryId)
   { 
       $country = $this->countryRepository->findById($countryId);
       $user = new User();
       $user->setCountry($country);

       $this->em->persist($user);
       $this->em->flush();

       return $user;
   }
   ```

   You have to add the CountryRepository as a dependency in your service.
2. add the countryID column as a attribute to your UserEntity

   in your User entity:

   ```
   /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
   */
   protected $countryId;

   /**
    * @return int
    */
   public function getCountryId()
   {
       return $this->countryId;
   }

   /**
    * @param int $countryId
    */
   public function setCountryId($countryId)
   {
       $this->countryId = $countryId;
   }
   ```

   in your user Service:

   ```
   public function registerUser($countryId)
   { 
       $user = new User();
       $user->setCountryId($countryId);

       $this->em->persist($user);
       $this->em->flush();

       return $user;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user->setCountry($country);
```

You have defined country as class in your `USER` entity so you need to assign country as object instead of string. You are passing string instead of country object.

Pass the country object in `registerUser($country)` instead of string, it won't give this exception.

Comment: I have defined it in my User service. Look above.